# How is total memory in Java calculated

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

If I have 8GB RAM and I use the following on a 64-bit JVM

- max heap size 6144MB
- max perm gen space 2048MB
- stack size 2MB

**Q1** : Is perm gen space allocated from the max heap or a separate?

**Q2** : if seperate then will the jvm with above settings get started or it will give error as heap + permgen + stack + program data would be above the total RAM?

Answer (score 5):

First of all remember that the parameter you set with `-Xmx` (since that's the way I suppose you are setting your heap size) is the size of heap available to your Java code, not the amount of memory the JVM will consume. The difference comes from housekeeping structures that the JVM keeps (garbage collector structures, JIT overhead etc.), sometimes memory allocated by native code, buffers, and so on. The size of this additional memory depends on JVM version, the app you are running, and other factors, but I've seen JVMs allocate twice as much RAM as the heap size visible to the application. For the average case, I usually consider 50% to be a safe margin, with 20-30% acceptable. If you set your heap size to be close to amount of RAM in your machine, you will hit the swap and performance will suffer.

Now for the enumerated questions:

Perm gen is a separate space from the heap at least in Oracle's JDK 6. It is separate because it undergoes completely different memory management rules than the regular heap. By the way, 2 GB of pergen space is huge - are you sure you really need it?

Regarding the second question, see above. If this is Oracle's JDK, you are likely to run into trouble since perm and heap sums up but there will be additional memory, usually on the order of 20-50% of your 6 GB heap, and together with heap and perm space this will be more than your RAM. At first try this setup may work, but once both the heap and perm gen space usages come close to their configured limits, you could run out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

heap and permgen are different memory parts of JVM. As such you will be consuming virtually all the memory on system. It is always better to leave 20% ram to be free for os/other tasks to execute properly.

Also, 2 gb for perm space is a huge figure. Have you looked at jar optimisation meaning that only relevant classes are present in the classpath?

Comment: thx ... the sizes were indicative ... but read somewhere that permgen is space reserved out of the heap ... n i think one has to take into account lots of other memry requirements too like  the stack per thread and other memory requirements per jvm instance ... whats jar optimization?

Comment: can jvm not use swap similar to the os ... instead of the dreaded OOM error?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the JVM and the version of the JVM.

- In Hotspot **Java 6**, **PermGen** space is **independent from** the **max heap** size argument (`-Xmx` and `-Xms` control only the Young/OldGen sizes). The PermGen space size is given by the `-XX:PermSize` and `-XX:MaxPermSize`. See [Java SE 6 HotSpot[tm] Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html)
- **UPDATE:** In Hotspot **Java 8**, there is **no PermGen space anymore** and the objects reside in the Young/Old Generation spaces.

Comment: PermGen is completely removed in Java 8, not 7. Just interned Strings are removed from PermGen in Java 7, class metadata is still there. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/enhancements-7.html